# Adding a delay between key pressing

Tags: c++

I am using `GetAsyncKeyState()` to get the input every frame for a game that I'm making.

I want to move one `x` at each press, but not every frame, there has to be a delay. I currently I am doing this by having a cool down each time you press a key.

Here are some parts of my `CoolDown` class:

```
bool test(bool asumedStatus)
{
    if(asumedStatus == status)
    {
        return true;
    } else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

void go()
{
    if(currentCount == runFor)
    {
        status = OFF_COOLDOWN;
    } else
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}

void start()
{
    currentCount = 0;
    status = ON_COOLDOWN;
}
```

`controls` gets called every frame to get the user input

```
void controls()
{
    if(test(OFF_COOLDOWN))
    {
        if(KEY_L && !KEY_R && !KEY_U && !KEY_D)
        {
            left();
            print();
            cd.start();
        }
        else if(KEY_R && !KEY_L && !KEY_D && !KEY_U)
        {
            right();
            print();
            cd.start();
        } else if(KEY_U && !KEY_L && !KEY_D && !KEY_R)
        {
            up();
            print();
            cd.start();
        } else if(KEY_D && !KEY_L && !KEY_R && !KEY_U)
        {
            down();
            print();
            cd.start();
        }
    } else
    {
        cd.go();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work, the delay isn't there. Nothing changed.

Does someone have any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Did you try to give `runFor` really big number? Simple game can run thousands of frames per second and game without graphic even millions of fps. Also better idea is to use time as Rakete1111 proposed. BTW. Why `test()` is not `cd.test()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

---

<sup>I use time to indicate frames, or ticks of the game.</sup>

I would make 2 variables:

- `startTime` - Time point when the delay started
- `currentTime` - Current time

Now, every tick, I'll update `currentTime` (by 1).

By taking the difference between those variables, you get the elapsed time since the start of the delay.

If the difference is *greater* than `delay`, then I have to reset the variables, to start all over again. So, setting `startTime` to `currentTime`, and setting `currentTime` to `0`.

If the difference is *less* than `delay`, do nothing, because the delay isn't "done".

Something like:

```
startTime = 0;
currentTime = 0;
delay = 2000; //In frames/ticks

//Called every frame/tick
void update() {
    ++currentTime; //Update time

    if (currentTime - startTime > delay) {
        //Reset
        startTime = currentTime;
        currentTime = 0;

        //Update whatever requires a delay
    }
}
```